# Time intervals with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have to draw a set of rect that represent the range of a day in the month.

```
svg.selectAll(".month")
  .data(function() { return getMonths(year); })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "month")
  .attr("d", monthPath);
```

My function is:

```
function getMonths(year){
   var months = d3.time.months(new Date(year, 0, 1), new Date(year + 1, 0, 1));
   return months;
}
```

This function is called for a set of year like [2003,2004,2005 and so on..]
If I call my function for a set of year it doesn't work, instead if I call this function in this way for all years:

```
function getMonths(year){
   var months = d3.time.months(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date(2012 + 1, 0, 1));
   return months;
}
```

it works.

Why I have this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `year` is being passed correctly?  Do a `console.log(year)` before you try calling `getMonths(year)`.

Comment: Yes, console.log(year) returns the correct value!

Comment: I have solved! The problem was that the typeof(years) === String and not an int.